# When my whole page has 'position: absolute', how do I check if I am at the top or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fixed, absolute

I have a main menu at the top of the website which when the user scrolls, changes and becomes more compact.

I was achieving that by checking scrolling events and whether we're at the top or not. 
This is the code that *was* working:

```
/*Defines how the 'main menu' will be displayed when we scroll down (if) and how it will fallback to original look when we're up again (else)*/
$(document).ready(function(){   
    if ($(window).width() > 480){                //not on mobile, then:
    $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
        $('.visible-bar-container').css("position", "fixed");
        $("#white-logo").css("display", "none");
        //...etc

    } else {
        $('.visible-bar-container').css("position", "absolute");
        $("#spread-out-menu").css("display", "flex");
        //...etc
        }
    });
    }
});
```

Mid project, the client decides that he wants the sections of the homepage to have a 'smooth scroll'. Long story short, I managed to do that after giving the whole homepage a CSS of position: absolute.

In case it matters, here is the whole CSS added to my homepage (which falls inside an element with id='main'):

```
#main {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

The problem is that now, the js code no longer works. (I believe that when the whole page has position absolute, checking for scrolling events no longer works-?). How then, can I check if the user has scrolled?

I might try checking whether user has moved past first section (through seeing if the div is visible in the viewport), but I would prefer the menu to become compact once we started moving down, not after the whole section has been moved past. So is there a way to check scrolling in this case?

Comment: try to use `$('#main').scrollTop()` instead of `$(window).scrollTop()`

Comment: Didn't work :/ but thank you for the suggestion anyway

Comment: do you have also changed `$(window).bind('scroll', function () {....` to  `$('#main').bind('scroll', function () { ....` ?

Comment: Okay it was my mistake. Now after I changed the .bind(scroll) to also act on '#main" it worked. Thank you, I am really grateful. This is my first wordpress project and I am googling obvious stuff most of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am the OP - so the answer was provided by Sim1-81 in the comments above. The trick was to change the third and fourth lines in the javascript:

```
...
 $("#main").bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($("#main").scrollTop() > 0) {
...
```

Where #main in my case is the id of the of page which I set to be 'position: absolute'.